Story about the Chofetz Chaim being sworn in as a witness in a secular court
I remember hearing a story about the Chofetz Chaim being sworn in as a witness in a secular court.  Can anyone tell me a source for this story, or give me more details?  I'm 90% sure it was the Chofetz Chaim, but maybe it was some other gadol?
The story goes (as far as I can remember) that after he was sworn in, he was asked to tell about himself, so he started to list all of his accomplishments and qualifications.  The Judge then said, "We heard that you were a righteous, humble person, what's with all of this boasting?  The Chofetz Chaim answered, "I swore to tell the whole truth."

It's usually told about R' Yechezkel Abramsky. Here's Ohr Somayach's version:

When the practice of ritual slaughter was under attack in Great
Britain, the famed Rabbi Yechezkel Abramsky was called to court in its
defense.
The judge read from the deposition which lay before him: "Rabbi
Abramsky," said the judge, "it says here that you are the foremost
authority of Jewish Law in the British Empire. Is that true?" "That is
true, your honor."
"And that you are the most eloquent spokesman for Jewish Law in the
British Empire?"
"That is also true, your honor."
"It also says here that you are the most senior rabbi in the British
Empire. Is that correct?"
"That is correct, your Honor."
Taken aback by the Rabbi's straight-forward responses, the judge said,
"Rabbi Abramsky, how do you resolve your answers with the Talmudic
teachings of humility?"
"It is indeed a problem, your honor," said the Rabbi. "But I'm under
oath."


And the context is a shochet who tried suing the London Beis Din. Rabbi Abramsky's expertise was material to the court case.

Is that a real response?

@Coreofreality Are you asking if it's a relevant and clear response or if it historically happened as described?

Historically happened
